# Only select certain items from related table using linq

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I have a 2 tables BlogPost and BlogComments

I want to get all BlogPosts that have a state of "published".
and get all BlogComments for each post that has a state of "published".

Im using something like this to get the blogposts:

```
var BlogPosts = (from p in db.BlogPosts where p.State == State.Published select p).ToArray();
```

but due to the relationship with BlogComments it autiomatically has all the BlogComments (both published and unpublished).

How can I just get the "published" comments for each of the blogposts (i.e the approved ones)

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try selecting a new BlogPostViewModel, an analog to BlogPost but with an `IEnumerable<BlogComment>` instead, with just the blog post data and a collection of published comments.

```
    select new BlogPostViewModel {
        Title = p.Title,
        Body = p.Body,
        Comments = p.Comments.Where( c => c.Published );
    });
```

Where `BlogPostViewModel` is:

```
public class BlogPostViewModel
{
     public string Title { get; set; }
     public string Body { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<BlogComment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ive tried this... 
           return (from p in db.BlogPosts 
                    where p.State == State.Published
                    select new BlogPost {
                    Title = p.Title,
                    Body = p.Body,
                    BlogComments = p.BlogComments.Where(c => c.State == State.Published)
                    }).ToArray();

but getting cannot convert ienumerable to entityset...:(

Comment: The I would suggest a separate ViewModel type that's an analog to BlogPost that has the Comments as an `IEnumerable<BlogComment>`

Comment: Could I just change the private EntitySet<BlogComment> _BlogComments; field into an ineumerable in the designer.cs file?

Comment: @raklos -- no you wouldn't want to do that.  Any changes you make to the designer go away if you ever change your model.  You might be able to add a partial class implementation that uses the EntitySet if available, but allows you to override it, but IMO that's ugly and error prone.   A view-specific model is usually the way to go anyway -- give your display logic just the data it needs in the form it needs it.  Using a view model decouples the view even further from the data model, since you can change the view model depending on your needs without altering the underlying data model.

Answer (score 0):

```
var BlogPosts = from p in db.BlogPosts where p.State == State.Published select new {
    Post = p,
    Comments = (from c in db.BlogComments where c.State == State.Published && c.Post = p select c)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var publishedComments = db.BlobPosts.Where(p => p.State == State.Published)
                                    .SelectMany(p => p.Comments)
                                    .Where(c => c.State == State.Published);
```

Sorry for not using the query syntax.  Hopefully this will get you on your way though.